# The use of the word "yet" in context

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Tell me please if I used *yet* correctly in the following sentence.

> For this exercise we could use a rubber band, but unfortunatly we don't have one **yet**.

I have noticed that natives predominantly use *yet* with the perfect tenses, so I am curious if it sounds grammatically OK with the present simple.

Comment: "we don't have one yet" implies you will have one not too much later. Does that fit your intent?

Comment: Yes, it what I meant